# Issue with jUnit file names

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit

I made some jUnit test, after some time I decided to rename it.

The names that are seen below in the picture are the right ones.
But when I do right-click, run jUnit test, I see the test with their previous names.

How can I correct this? I did maven clean, maven install, build the project again, but the issue persist.

[image]

Comment: Haven't used Eclipse in ages, but I guess Eclipse saves run configurations, which remember the old names. Just delete these old run configurations and make new ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Select the old test configuration in Run configuration and you can remove by clicking "x" as shown in image